# Using temperature data obtained over UART as part of hwmon/thermal subsystem

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, sensors

I am attempting to integrate an OEM module into a product that runs embedded Linux.  I am only able to communicate with the module through a UART, and the most important thing that I need to get from it is its temperature.

The system is an ARM-based system and I already have a thermal design using an I2C temperature sensor and fan with the device tree and everything working great.  The addition of this module is where things begin to get tricky.  The OEM module is an option, and may or may not be present in a given system.  The hardware needs to detect the presence of the OEM module and load the appropriate kernel modules/device tree overlays to enable thermal management of the installed hardware.

The difficult thing here is that there does not seem to be a thermal sensor that communicates over UART.  I have found drivers for SPI ([LM70](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/drivers/hwmon/lm70.c)), I2C ([LM75](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/drivers/hwmon/lm75.h)), and 1-Wire ([DS18S20](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/w1/slaves/w1_therm.c)) temperature sensors, but there is no precedent for using asynchronous serial in conjunction with the Linux thermal subsystem.

My initial plan was to read the temperature in the Userspace and write it to the thermal subsystem.  This is not allowed (for good reason) unless you enable set_emul_temp in the kernel config.  I would prefer not to allow userspace code to write to all of my temperature sensors and thereby override the actual temperature of the system, so I'm pursuing a different strategy.

Plan 2 was to write a kernel module that "plugs in" to the hwmon subsystem that has a writeable attribute.  This way, I can configure the thermal control scheme to use whichever temperature sensor is higher to control the fan.  If malicious code overrides the OEM module temperature control, the on-board I2C sensor will still be reading correctly and the fan will run according to the read temperature.  As I have dug into this, I am not certain this is possible either.

The final plan would be to figure out how to share the UART between a kernel module and a userspace TTY driver.  The kernel module could register itself with hwmon and obtain a lock on the device driver while accessing the temperature value (4 bytes @ ~900k baud), leaving the device open to use from userspace applications when not sampling the temperature.  The refresh period of the temperature value is not critically important, as long as the temperature is updated every second or so, so a userspace application using the device would not cause significant problems, as all transfers between the system and the OEM module will be relatively small (>500B).

I started developing a kernel module based upon a couple of very nice guides written by [Robert W Oliver II](https://blog.sourcerer.io/writing-a-simple-linux-kernel-module-d9dc3762c234) and [Derek Molloy](http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-2-a-character-device/).  These have allowed me to write a module that holds a value written to it for later use.  The next task I have tried to accomplish is how to integrate this into hwmon.  This took me to [The Linux Hardware Monitoring kernel API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/hwmon/hwmon-kernel-api.html).

The problem I ran into is that my char device does not seem to have a parent device, so I cannot call `devm_hwmon_device_register_with_info`.  It also does not seem that I can register as a hwmon device AND a char device.  I am now looking into registering my driver as a platform driver using `module_platform_driver` in order to call `devm_hwmon_device_register_with_info` inside `.probe()`.  That seems like it may get me to the point where I have a "device" registered with hwmon, even though I will be unable to write to it.

In the absence of a method for writing to the device from the userspace, I am thinking that I will need to resort to directly interfacing with the serial port as part of the module.  This gets even more confusing, as it appears to be much less clearly defined than with I2C or SPI.  I am led to [The Lockronomicon](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/serial/tty.html) and Line Disciplines as the likely solution here, but I hesitate to dig into this if it's not the correct path.

Given the constraints I have listed, do any of my options seem like the correct path?  Has this type of thing been done before?  I am unable to find any evidence that someone has solved this problem before me, so I am struggling with the ins and outs of fitting into the kernel's design.  It would be great if I could simply overwrite the fan speed with something higher, but this sort of functionality seems to be locked away from userspace (again, for good reason).

Comment: I would think you could just read it, say in C (after checking for exists via some kind of shell script). Have you checked things [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944461/linux-reading-data-from-uart), [or this linked discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c/6947758#6947758) or (I doubt this will work) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947413/how-to-open-read-and-write-from-serial-port-in-c/6947758#6947758)?

Comment: @number9, the mechanics of reading and writing to/from the UART/TTY from a userspace application are not an issue.  The issue arises in getting a value read from a TTY in a userspace application and putting it into the thermal control system.  I have an application that reads/writes to the needed port, but I have no method for getting that read data into the Linux hwmon/thermal subsystem from a userspace application, hence the need for a kernel module.  Perhaps I failed to explain this in my question?

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I suppose that got lost on me when I started thinking about reading the UART.

Comment: Understandable. It's a long and somewhat complicated question, but I wanted to make sure I didn't leave information out.